# JSF 1.2 outputText tag generates a span

Tags: jsf, tomahawk

I am new to JSF 1.2,
I am trying to output some text into my javascript call like so

```
something(<t:outputText value="#{bean.val}"/>)
```

but instead of getting plain text output, this is all being wrapped in a **span**. How do i get rid of the span?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure about `t:outputText`, but an `h:outputText` **without** any other attribute than `value` should *not* render any HTML element.

```
something(<h:outputText value="#{bean.val}"/>);
```

If you're using `id`, `styleClass` or something like that, then it will indeed render a `<span>` since those attributes has to get somewhere anyway.

If you're using Facelets as view technology instead of legacy JSP, then you could also just use EL in template text like follows:

```
something(#{bean.val})
```

Answer (score 1):

what about simply putting:

```
something("#{bean.val}");
```

Comment: that's strange. I'm almost sure it works fine in JSF 1.2 as well. (+1 for which)

Comment: Correction: only on Facelets. JSP doesn't support that.